Enabling SQL Developer Web to access my SQL Workspace
I recently created SQL Workspace in https://apex.oracle.com, I then registered the schema with ODS. When I try to select on Apex SQL Workshop -> SQL Developer Web it launches and then disappears. I don't have any error message to diagnose. I believe it used to work, so what am I missing in configuration?

Run SQL Developer from a command prompt (rather than clicking on an icon) then when it disappears you should be able to see any messages that it outputs to the console and that will (hopefully) give you something to use in debugging the issue.

It's a bug. The APEX team is working on a fix.
You did nothing wrong.

Is there a public-facing ticket (URL) for this, so anyone interested can check for status updates?

no, but your my oracle support portal would allow you track bugs
